# Caesar cipher by comparing char array with two arrays

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, char

I need to build a Caesar cipher that only encrypts letters, but no special characters. My concept was, to compare the input char[] with two alphabet char[]. If there is no match in a char, the char should be added to the String without being changed. The problem is that the not-changed char will be added to the String until the the for-loop ends. How do I fix this?

```java
public static String encrypt(String text, int number) {
    String str = "";
    char[] chars = text.toCharArray();
    char[] al = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
    char[] ab = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toUpperCase().toCharArray();

    for (char c : chars) {
        boolean match = false;

        for (int i = 1; i < chars.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int k = 0; (k < al.length || k < ab.length) && !match; k++) {
                match = (c == al[k] || c == ab[k]);

                if (match) {
                    c += number;
                    str += c;
                }
            }

            if (!match) {
                str += c;
            }
        }
    }

    return str;
}
```

I already tried to put the case for not changing the string within the other for-loop, but it will be added until the for-loop has reached it's end.

Comment: You seem to be making this more complex than it need be. A: change all input characters to the same case and B: ignore any character that's not a letter. That's it - now you can get on with implementing the actual cipher ;)

Comment: The term is cipher, not chiffre (unless you're talking about [César Chiffre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A9sar_Chiffre), which is unlikely given the context ;)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would tackle the problem by iterating through the String and considering the possible cases for each letter

- Uppercase Letter
- Lowercase Letter
- Special Character

  ```
  public static String encrypt(String text, int number) {

    //String to hold our return value
    String toReturn = "";

    //Iterate across the string at each character
    for (char c : text.toCharArray()){

        if (Character.isUpperCase(c)){

            /* If uppercase, add number to the character
            If the character plus number is more than 90,
            subtract 25 [uppercase letters have ASCII 65 to 90] */
            toReturn += c + number > 90 ? (char)(c + number - 25) : (char)(c + number);

        } else if (Character.isLowerCase(c)){

            /* If lowercase, add number to the character
            If the character plus number is more than 122,
            subtract 25 [uppercase letters have ASCII 97 to 122] */
            toReturn += c + number > 122 ? (char)(c + number - 25) : (char)(c + number);

        } else {

            // For other characters, just add it onto the return string
            toReturn += c;

        }

    }

    return toReturn;

  }
  ```

**Explanation of Code**

You might be wondering what the following code does

`toReturn += c + number > 90 ? (char)(c + number - 25) : (char)(c + number)`

The structure is

`toReturn += CONDITION ? A : B`

It basically reads as

`IF CONDITION IS TRUE, toReturn += A, ELSE toReturn += B`

The `CONDITION` is simply `c + number > 90` since we want to make sure that we are sticking with uppercase letters only

When this is true (`A`), we subtract `25` from `c + number`, otherwise (`B`) we just keep it as `c + number` (B)

We then cast this value into a `char` since it is initially an `int`